# Some questions about start a new stream in libp2p host

Tags: libp2p

First question is: When a host try to start a new stream to a remote with some streamhandler in libp2p, it seems the remote peer would automatically start a goroutine to handle this stream, while the local peer need to manually start this handler. What is the purpose of such design?

Second question is: If some remote peer start a new stream or connect my local host, can I monitor the inbound stream or get the inbound stream. Something like net.Listener.Accept().If so which method should I use.

Thank you.

Comment: One more questions, how can the host set the maximum inbound and outbound streams.  Or can the host monitor the streams and manage them. If there are too many streams,  which one would the host close first?

Comment: You would better ask three questions in three posts separately,  otherwise people do not have  motivation to  answer you.